# Django syncdb can't find my apps

Tags: django, syncdb

I'm a django newbie and have been having a problem.

In my project root I created a folder called 'local_apps'  and within it I put the app 'myapp'. I updated the INSTALLED_APPS within settings.py with: myproject.local_apps.myapp

However when I try to syncbd, Django gives an error: 'no module named local_apps.myapp exists'

When I put 'myapp' back in the project root, it works again but I dont want it that way. I want to keep my apps in the folder 'local_apps'.

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that's a generic python error, not a Django error.

Maybe you need to create an `__init__.py` file in the local_apps directory, so python knows it's a module.

Comment: Wow that was fast. Thanks wisty, that worked. The syncdb works now. @dappawit, the models.py is present and is now being updated as it should.  Thanks again guys

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a `models.py` within the myapp folder?  I think Django may need to see that file in the app.

[Edit: actually, I think wisty above may be right, make sure you have an `__init__.py`, if you do, try the models.py.]

Comment: Wow that was fast. Thanks wisty, that worked. The syncdb works now. @dappawit, the models.py is present and is now being updated as it should.  Thanks again guys

Comment: sorry, double reply. As you can see, I'm new to Stackoverflow aswell.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the error: `ImportError: No module named foo`

To solve this, I just added the Django site package to the Python path at `settings.py` module like this:

```
PKG_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
sys.path.append(PKG_DIR)
```